# How to put id IS NOT NULL with escape varible ??/?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I tried to put 3 variations are included:

1. empty
2. version IS NOT NULL AND
3. version = ' + criteria.version + ' AND

I need use escape
Help please

this code is wrong, but for understanding I need like this:

```js
function getCriteria(criteria){
  var ver = '';

  if(criteria.version == null){
    ver = 'version IS NOT NULL AND';
  }
  else if(criteria.version > 0)
  {
    ver = 'version = ' + criteria.version + ' AND';
  }
  
  return mysql.getConnection((conn) => {
    return conn.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM hlrlookup.hlrlookup ' +
                           'WHERE ? create_timestamp < "2017-02-16 13:34:40"', [ver]).then............
```

Comment: I don't think you can.  The `?` is a placeholder for a parameter, not a snippet of code.

Comment: What exactly is the string at the end? Sounds like you just need `'WHERE '+ver+' create_timestamp`

Comment: @mplungjan, i started to use escape(??/?) for security but faced with snippet code, i don't want to use ordinary varibles

Comment: maybe together Es6 (${...} + ??) ? i dunno

Comment: Is this code in the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build the query text using regular string handling, but still use the parameterization for the case where you need it;

```
function getCriteria(criteria) {
  var ver = '';
  var parms = []

  if(criteria.version == null){
    ver = 'version IS NOT NULL AND';
  }
  else if(criteria.version > 0)
  {
    ver = 'version = ? AND';
    parms = [criteria.version]
  }

  return mysql.getConnection((conn) => {
    return conn.queryAsync(
        'SELECT * FROM hlrlookup.hlrlookup ' +
        'WHERE ' + ver + ' create_timestamp < "2017-02-16 13:34:40"', parms)
      .then............
```